# Why does bagging use bootstrap samples?

Tags: bagging

Bagging is the process of creating N learners on N different bootstrap samples, then taking the mean of their predictions.

My question is: Why not use any other type of sampling? Why use bootstrap samples?

Answer (score 9):

Interesting question.  The bootstrap has good sampling properties, compared to some alternatives like the jackknife.  The main downside of bootstrapping is that every iteration has to work with a sample that's as big as the original data set (which can be computationally expensive), while some other sampling techniques can work with much smaller samples.

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5016) suggests that naïvely cutting the sample size can reduce performance, relative to bootstrap-based bagging, which would be a reason not to do so.  The paper also introduces a novel method for using smaller samples in bagging estimates, while avoiding those problems.